# Apache Ignite 2.x BinaryObject deserialize performance

Tags: ignite

I'm observing two orders of magnitude performance difference scanning a local off-heap cache between binary and deserialized mode (200k/sec vs 2k/sec). Have not profiled it with tools yet.

Is the default reflection based binary codec a recommended one for production or there's a better one?

What's the best source to read for description of the binary layout (the official documentation is missing that)?

Or in the most generic form - what's the expected data retrieval performance with Ignite scanning query and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.0.0 version ignite stores all data in off heap memory, so it's expected that BinaryObjects works faster, because BinaryObject doesn't deserialize you objects to classes, but works directly with bytes.
So yes, it's recommended to use BinaryObjects if possible for performance sake.

Read the following doc:
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller
it explains how to use BinaryObjects.

Comment: Which part of the question does this answer?

Comment: @bobah "Is the default reflection based binary codec a recommended one for production or there's a better one?" - it's recommended.

Comment: about you last question, if you need so low level details, then source code is at your disposal.

Comment: The question is not really whether binary is faster and by how much, the question is how to get decent data fetching performance out of Ignite. I updated the question to make it unambiguous. And I am of cause aware of the source code availability.